# booleans in rails with sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, model, boolean

I am a bit of a noob still with rails, but I am running across something that seems a bit odd. I added a boolean field to a model in the database thusly

```
t.column :admin, :bool, :default => false, :null => false
```

However, the value in the sqlite3 database seems to be either `'t'` or `'f'`. That is fine, but I would still expect `user.admin?` to return false if the value is `'f'`. As you can see from the following console session, that's not the case:

```
>> user = User.first
=> #<User id: 2, login: "matt", name: "", email: "google.ninja@no-spam.com", crypt
ed_password: "c6740f820b4cbf6e3d88188719f23cd3053a54f0", salt: "5629f5ee09f51543
a7d64dd903b8d9e53aa43a24", created_at: "2009-04-26 23:08:05", updated_at: "2009-
04-26 23:10:38", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, admin: "t"
>
>> user.admin?
=> true
>> user.admin = false
=> false
>> user.save
=> true
>> user = User.first
=> #<User id: 2, login: "matt", name: "", email: "google.ninja@no-spam.com", crypt
ed_password: "c6740f820b4cbf6e3d88188719f23cd3053a54f0", salt: "5629f5ee09f51543
a7d64dd903b8d9e53aa43a24", created_at: "2009-04-26 23:08:05", updated_at: "2009-
05-06 03:32:23", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, admin: "f"
>
>> user.admin?
=> true
```

Is this just some weird issue with sqlite, or am I just not getting something?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but I think it probably has to do with Ruby/Rails, not SQLite per se.  SQLite does not actually have a boolean data type (see http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so it's the wrapper's responsibility to encode it somehow.  Typically, 1 or 0 would be used, but Rails may be doing something weird.  Also, remember that SQLite is weakly typed so you can put ints in your varchar columns, etc.  and this can cause pain (see http://chriscraig.net/blog/sqlite-boolean-true-or-false/ for relevant discussion) if you're not careful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
t.column :admin, :boolean, :default => false, :null => false
```

Read why [here](http://kconrails.com/blog/articles/2008/07/15/ruby-on-rails-bool-vs-boolean-in-sqlite3).

Comment: yeah, i figured it was something odd like that. Thanks :) +1 and marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with the database migration. I don't think that :bool is the right data type name to use. Try :boolean instead, e.g.

```
t.column :admin, :boolean, :default => false, :null => false
```