# Outputting booleans for Rails in Heroku gives "t" instead of "true" and "f" instead of false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just added two new columns to my Users table in Rails and found some *surprising* results on Heroku compared with my local environment, and when compared with earlier Heroku usage!  Do you know what might have happened?

This is the migration:

class AddMoreIntroFlagsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :has_seen_first_intro, :boolean, :null => false, :default => false
    add_column :users, :has_seen_store_intro, :boolean, :null => false, :default => false
  end
end

However, the following JavaScript in my view outputs t and f instead of true and false...

User.hasSeenStoreIntro = <%= signed_in? and current_user.has_seen_store_intro %>

converts to: (I was expecting true or false not t and f!)

User.hasSeenStoreIntro = t

This gives a JS error since t isn't defined!

Any idea why this would happen just for the new columns?  It never did that for my old columns.  A potentially related problem is that I ran a secure route to set user. has_seen_first_intro = true and user.has_seen_store_intro = true for all existing users, yet those columns did not update to true.  I had run similar code after adding earlier columns, and it used to work.  What changed now?

The only thing that I can think changed is that the number of users in my production table has grown significantly in the past few days.

Comment: Is there a difference between your local and Heroku environment?  What database is used in each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have `'t'` stored in your database for a true value for `current_user.has_seen_store_intro`, possibly because it was added by a different database adapter that supports booleans being stored as `'t'` and `'f'`. Let's assume that `signed_in?` returns `true` -- in which case:

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > a = true
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :009 > b = 't'
 => "t" 
1.9.3p194 :010 > a and b
 => "t"
```

That's in Heroku. In your dev environment your database adapter understand `'t'` and `'f'` as boolean values, therefore it returns `true`.

Just a possibility.

Comment: This is wrong example. `and` operator will give you always true because other string('t' or 'f') will always be true(because not nil)

Comment: what is wrong about it? it plainly gives `'t'`, not `true`. `'t'` is obviously a truthy value, but that's of no significance to the question.

Comment: Logical `and` gives true if both all of arguments are true. String will always return `true`, no mater if its`'t`' or `'f`'. And ruby's `&&` or `and` will always return last argument if case if result of operator is `true`. Try `'t' and 'f`'

Comment: i know all of that. i don't know what point you're trying to make. which part of my answer is wrong?

Comment: Using `a and b` with `b` as a string - will aways return truthy of `a`. And according to question of topic starter - `signed_in? and current_user.has_seen_store_intro` should produce some boolean value - using string type that indicates boolean as 't' or 'f' will return `true` even  if `current_user.has_seen_store_intro` will return `'f'`

Comment: i know all that and it has literally nothing to do with the question. you've still not explained which part of my answer is incorrect so i'll just ignore you now.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC Rails' SQLite adapter defaults booleans to t/f

To be DB agnostic, you could try to use Rails' automatic evaluation of boolean fields

```
signed_in? and current_user.has_seen_store_intro?
```

edit:
If fact that may not work, and you might want to try to solution as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827938/booleans-in-rails-with-sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

Anybody still facing this issue on heroku, Try to restart app

```
heroku restart --app yourappname
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer actually. It was this simple, thanks!